# How to determine ctrl is pressed before clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script which gives user the URL of specific element *(current URL plus the #id of element as anchor)*. My script executes when user clicks on the element, ok, that isn't what I want, I want this:

**If *ctrl* is pressed and user clicks on the element, then script below run. And then copy that URL in the clipboard of user's system.**

How can I do that?

```js
// I need to write a condition here to check whether ctrl is pressed?

$("div").on("click", function(){
  var url              =  window.location.href;
  var anchor        =  $(this).attr("id");
  var url_of_elm =  url + "#" + anchor;
  
  console.log(url_of_elm);
  
  // I need to copy url_of_elm in the clipboard of the user

  alert("URL of element is copied");

});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "1">
  <h2>title1</h2>
  <p>content1</p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>

<div id = "2">
  <h2>title2</h2>
  <p>content2 <span>the rest of content2</span></p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>

<div id = "3">
  <h2>title3</h2>
  <p>content3 <a>a link in the content3</a></p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
```

in

```
$("div").on("click", function(event){
```

and then inside check

```
if(event.ctrlKey){
    \\Ctrl key is pressed!
```

**EDIT:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/m2x4obv1/1/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually they do. Also shiftKey prop

Comment: Actually I need to copy that URL in the clildhood of user's system, is that possible?

Comment: @stack where is the link you have to copy exactly? You can achieve it with jQuery.find([childrenWithLinkInsideIt] and then read the url.

Comment: I need to copy the content of `url_of_elm` variable in the childboard of user's system.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "childboard of user's system"

Comment: What happens when you mark a text and press R-click and choose *Copy* ? Marked text will be copied in your childboard. Now I want to copy the content of `url_of_elm` in the childboard of user's system.

Comment: @stack: I think the confusion is over your use of "childboard" instead of "clipboard".

Comment: @Charles Oh .. yeah you are right .. tnx for the tip

Comment: Copying to the clipboard is not easy, since Javascript doesn't usually allow to interfere with user data (including clipboard). There are some ways to do so but it's not widely supported. You should do it with document.execCommand('copy') but you better search here on StackOverflow or on Google, there are already answers about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by hooking a keydown and keyup event listener to the document which sets a flag indicating whether or not the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is being pressed. You can then check this flag in your click handler. Try this:

```js
ctrlKeyDown = false;

$(document).on({ 
    keydown: function(e) {
        ctrlKeyDown = e.ctrlKey;
    },
    keyup: function() {
        ctrlKeyDown = false;
    }
});

$("div").on("click", function(){
    if (ctrlKeyDown) {
        var url =  window.location.href;
        var anchor =  $(this).attr("id");
        var url_of_elm =  url + "#" + anchor;
        alert(url_of_elm);
    }
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "1">
  <h2>title1</h2>
  <p>content1</p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>

<div id = "2">
  <h2>title2</h2>
  <p>content2 <span>the rest of content2</span></p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>

<div id = "3">
  <h2>title3</h2>
  <p>content3 <a>a link in the content3</a></p>
  <span>something else</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. it works, +1. Just may you please copy that URL in the childhood of user's system?

Comment: @LucaDeNardi to make it work cross browser there is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what browser doesn't have those flags in the click event?

Comment: Older versions of IE I believe, and possibly on OSX too. I don't have one here to test on at the moment. I agree your version is by far the most elegant, but if you need legacy browser support the version above is what is required.

Comment: Copying the content of `url_of_elm` variable in the clipboard is not possible?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan don't think that's correct. The properties have been in mouse event object since jQuery 1.0 (2006) http://plnkr.co/edit/kvWMBYF7vy5wB81xlCtF?p=preview

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan event.ctrlKey as well as all others flags are correctly set from OSX. Since the OP didn't specify what browser is it targeting, I thought to show the easiest way to check those flags